# How to add msbuild generated files to Azure package

Tags: msbuild, azure

I am using the YUI compressor MSBuild task to combine/minify css/js files. The files are generated by the MSBuild task and everything works great locally. The problem I have is I need to deploy this to Azure and the MSBuild generated files are not being added to the package. I've tried running the YUI Compressor task in pre-build and post-build, but the files still don't make it to azure.

So, question is, how do I add msbuild generated files to an Azure package.

My web project is MVC 3 if that matters..

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Can you give me an example about how did you do it please?

Comment: @iboware I ended up adding the generated files to the project so they get deployed. Not ideal, but works w/ minimal effort...

Comment: Yeah. :) I'm working with this issue for 2 days and I couldn't find anything to fix it. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at Tom Hollander's blog post 'Automated Build and Deployment with Windows Azure SDK 1.6', he discuss MsBuild for Azure here...

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tomholl/archive/2011/12/06/automated-build-and-deployment-with-windows-azure-sdk-1-6.aspx